# O que é chamada de método substituível no construtor?

Tags: java, netbeans

Em uma classe que extende `JFrame`, tenho algumas chamadas no construtor, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
 public ListaDeOficiosUI() {
        try {
            this.oficioController = new OficioController();
            this.initComponents();
            //o alerta é exibido nas 3 chamadas de métodos
           //  seguintes, todos da classe JFrame
            this.setTitle(GerOficiosUI.TITULO + " - Lista de Oficios");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            this.addWindowListener(
                    new WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                            GerOficiosUI x = new GerOficiosUI();
                            x.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                            x.setVisible(true);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                            requestFocus();
                        }
                    });
            this.setRowSorter();
        } catch (ExcecaoErroIO ex) {
            PrintMessageUI.exibirError(this.getInstance(), ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Porém, o netbeans fica salientando alguns trechos com a mensagem **Chamada de método substituível no construtor**, como pode ser visto no print abaixo:

[image: imagem da mensagem de alerta do netbeans]

O código não gera erros, executa normalmente sem nenhum tipo de problema.

O que significa essa mensagem de alerta? O fato de ignorá-la pode trazer algum problema na aplicação?

Comment: A função que ele reclama é um método virtual?

Comment: @RodrigoGuiotti não conheço este conceito de método virtual em java, não sei te afirmar isso :/

Comment: Se o método não é estático, privado ou final, ele pode ser substituído por outro através de herança e a classe que herda de ListaDeOficiosUI poderia alterar o comportamento do seu construtor.

Comment: @RodrigoGuiotti nenhuma classe herda `ListaDeOficiosUI`, é ela quem herda `JFrame`, pois é uma tela. Mas como uma classe filha pode sobrescrever o construtor da classe superior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## O que é

*Método substituível* quer dizer um método que pode ser sobrescrito por uma subclasse.

## O aviso

Este é apenas um *warning* da sua IDE sobre um problema em potencial, não necessariamente um erro nem algo inerente ao Java.

O problema neste caso é que seu construtor está dependendo de um método que pode ser sobrescrito por uma subclasse. Se isso ocorrer, a subclasse pode alterar o comportamento do método e tornar a construção da classe imprevisível.

Isso quebra o contrato da herança, pois se a subclasse quiser mudar o comportamento de inicialização, ela deve sobrescrever o construtor e não um método que afeta o construtor da superclasse.

Particularmente eu não considero este um caso muito grave. Na maioria dos casos, como deve ser este, esta simplesmente não é uma classe que será sobrescrita e isso nunca vai acontecer. Então eu simplesmente desligaria este aviso nas configurações da IDE.

Algumas IDEs permitem omitir o aviso no trecho de código, na classe, no projeto ou globalmente.

## A solução

Com certeza não é colocar a chamada num outro método `private` como diz a outra resposta, pois você simplesmente está adicionando um código desnecessário com o fim de omitir um aviso da IDE, mas que **não resolve em nada o possível problema apontado**, isto é, de permitir a sobrescrita de um método usado no construtor.

Se esta classe não é projetada ser herdada, a solução é simplesmente não fazer nada e desabilitar o aviso.

Se você está projetando a classe para herança, uma possível solução seria simplesmente tornar o método `setTitle` privado. Não faz sentido uma subclasse mudar algo que foi definido no construtor da superclasse.

Se a subclasse precisar mudar o título, adicione um novo construtor com um parâmetro `String titulo`. Exemplo:

```
public ListaDeOficiosUI() {
    this("Título default");
}
public ListaDeOficiosUI(String titulo) {
    ...
    this.setTitulo(titulo);
    ...
}
private setTitulo() { ... }
```

Dessa forma você mantém o comportamento esperado da superclasse e as classes filhas podem explicitamente alterar o título, deixando claro o contrato de comportamento na hierarquia.

## Nota sobre o `JFrame`

Como você está usando o método herdado de `JFrame`, não é possível alterar a visibilidade do `setTitulo` e dos outros métodos.

Neste caso específico, poderia usar o construtor do `JFrame` que já recebe o título. Exemplo

```
public ListaDeOficiosUI() {
    super("Meu Título");
}
```

Para os outros casos não tem muito jeito.

Entretanto, uma outra abordagem é não usar herança. Você **não** precisa estender `JFrame`! Pode simplesmente referenciar um atributo na sua classe que representa a tela, assim:

```
public class ListaDeOficiosUI {
    private JFrame frame;
    public ListaDeOficiosUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Título");
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Considero esta abordagem melhor porque evita herança onde ela simplesmente não é necessária.

## Considerações

Sugestão: evite usar IDEs em Português. Não digo mal de quem traduziu, mas tradução de termos técnicos dificilmente são confiáveis.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, minha classe já está herdando de `JFrame`é uma tela) e os métodos que dão esse warning são chamadas da classe que já estou herdando. Acho que vou deixar como estava mesmo, não pretendo reusar(ou herdar) minha classe pra outras coisas.

Comment: @DiegoF Certo, esqueci que você provavelmente estava herdando do `JFrame`. Nesse caso não tem problema mesmo, mas você também pode substituir o caso do título por uma chamada ao construtor da superclasse, porque `Jframe` tem um construtor que recebe o título. Exemplo: `super("Meu Título");` na primeira linha do construtor.

Answer (score 0):

A forma de corrigir este problema é não utilizar métodos que são substituíveis (já que Java não usa a palavra virtual) dentro do construtor.

Só utilize métodos estáticos, privados ou finais nos construtores.

Comment: Mas os métodos que dão o alerta não são da minha classe, são da classe que a minha herdou, como vou modificar a assinatura de algo herdado?

Comment: Você consegue alterar a classe JFrame?

Comment: Na verdade, ela é da API swing, [veja](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). Eu só estou reutilizando ela.

Comment: Ah sim. Então basta você tirar do construtor os métodos que você está usando que poderão ser modificados. Pelo que vi no seu print, setTitle, setDefaultCloseOperation e addWindowListener.

Comment: Isso me obrigaria a ter que criar métodos pra sobrescrever quase todos os métodos da classe pai, o código ia ficar bagunçado. Ao invés de chamar no construtor, se eu jogar essas chamadas substituiveis em outro método privado e chamar este método privado no construtor, contorna a mensagem ne?

Comment: Isso, por essa razão eu editei a resposta, para deixar isso mais claro.

Comment: Agora que percebi seu comentário na resposta sobre isso mesmo, valeu! :)

Answer (score -1):

No NetBeans, com a janela do projeto aberta,  resolvi o problema clicando:

```
Navegador -> JFrame -> Eventos -> componenteResized.
```

No código :

```
setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```